# How to add CSS and JS files on node pages from theme's template.php

Tags: javascript, theming

I am trying to add JavaScript and CSS files to one node type page from my template.php file but it is not working.  Here is my template.php code:

```
<?php
// $Id: template.php,v 1.13 2010/12/14 01:04:27 dries Exp $

function mttheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
  if ($node->type = 'sales_team_page') {
    drupal_add_css('misc/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css');
    drupal_add_js('misc/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js',
      array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'header')
    );
    drupal_add_js('misc/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js',
      array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'header')
    );
    drupal_add_js('misc/jquery.fancybox-calls.js',
      array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'header')
    );
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why it is not working?

Comment: this belongs in Drupal Answers!

Answer (score 7):

Since you want your CSS and JavaScript when displaying a node, you can add the files it in the preprocess function for the node template. Also, as stated in their documentation, when adding a file, the first argument for [`drupal_add_css()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) and [`drupal_add_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) is the path the CSS/JavaScript file **relative to the base_path()**. You can use `drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME')` to get the path of your theme relative to the base path.

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['view_mode'] == 'full') {
    $node =& $variables['node'];
    if ($node->type == 'sales_team_page') {
      $path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME');
      drupal_add_css($path . '/misc/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css');
      drupal_add_js($path . '/misc/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js', array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'header'));
      drupal_add_js($path . '/misc/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js', array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'header'));
      drupal_add_js($path . '/misc/jquery.fancybox-calls.js', array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'header'));
    }
  }
}
```

Also, doing `$node = node_load(arg(1));` to load the currently viewed node is unsafe and wrong. If you have a *non node* page at `whatever/42` but have an existing `sales_team_page` node with nid = 42, you will load this node and add your CSS and JavaScript files even if the user is not viewing the node.

Comment: any idea how to add #attached['js'] here ?

Comment: You can't use #attached here. In order to use #attach you need to be able to alter the renderable array  before it is rendered through `drupal_render()`. For rendered node, this can be done in `hook_node_view()` or `hook_entity_view()`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you dont get the node type correctly.
Use preprocess node in order to capture the node type correctly.

```
function mttheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
 if ($variables['type'] == "sales_team_page"){
   drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mttheme') . 'misc/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css');
   //add js in the same way using drupal_get_path()
 }
}
```

You can also add them through your .info file of your theme :

```
name = Your theme
core = 7.x
engine = phptemplate


scripts[] = my_js.js
```

Comment: I only want to add it to one page, I do not want it to appear on every page.  That is why I do not use the .info file.  I tried changing the code to what you have but it still doesnt work...

Comment: hmmm from what i see a lot changed in d7.In order to get node type in preprocess_html you need a lot of stuff....just do a var_dump to $variables to see what it gets to get to content type.
You could also check bartik's template.php to see how it adds js.
You probably need the full path not the relative, using path_to_theme()

Comment: @zach edited accordingly.i hope this helps now

Comment: It is not working.  At this point I am starting to think that my theme never reads template.php.  Could there be something wrong with that file?  Do I have to do anything else besides place the code in the template.php file?  I have it in the root of my sites/all/themes/mytheme/ folder.  I also started it with <?php and left it open.  What else do I need to do?

Comment: you could clear your cache from performance..
cache can be a bitch a lot of times..if clearing cache wont work as well something else fails...
maybe your content-type is not called 'sales_team_page'?
Also get http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer  .. it really helps to drupal theming

Comment: I have cleared the cache multiple times. I am pretty sure thats not the case.  The fact is I have never been able to get any of my template.php code to work.  The content type is sales_team_page.  I have even tried sales-team-page.  I am not sure how the develop theme module will work. I will try it out though.

Comment: do this to find out if your template.php works:

     function mttheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
      print_r($variables);
     }
then load a node..if nothing appears then your template doesnt work indeed.
if you get an array then it works and there is something wrong with the code:/

Comment: I tried that and nothing happened.

Comment: ok,where exactly is your template.php?
have you activated the theme you have the template.php in?
also,is mttheme your theme's name?

Comment: Yes to all of those.  The file is located in sites/all/themes/mttheme/template.php