# Add javascript to a specific node

Tags: javascript, path-aliases, theming

I want to add some extra javascript (few files stored in my account, and some inline javascript) for a specific node. Based on [the answer to this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4586/how-to-add-css-and-js-files-on-node-pages-from-themes-template-php), I tried adding a few files to the node alias "insert-pub" by doing this in the template.php in /themes/garland (just trying out the garland theme for now):

```
  function garland_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
     // The line below was already there.
     $vars['submitted'] = $vars['date'] . ' â€” ' . $vars['name'];
     // Added the lines below.
     // Want to include my javascript files and inline scripts for specific nodes.
     $node =& $vars['node'];
     debug($node);
     debug($node->type);
     if ($node->type == 'insert-pub')
     {
          drupal_add_js('/sites/all/scripts/MyLib.js', array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'header'));
          drupal_add_js('/sites/all/scripts/Utils.js', array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'header'));
          drupal_add_js('var MyAjaxLib=new MyLib();         
               function loadInput(){ alert("Hello"); }', 'inline');
     }
}
```

But I never see the links to the JS files or inline JS scripts in the source of the page, when I load the page in the browser by going to [www.mysite.com/insert-pub]. Where am I going wrong? Even the debug() calls above does not seem to print anything in the browser.

I am a Drupal 7 newbie, so looking forward to some hand-holding. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The node type will always have an underscore as the separator (not a dash) between words so the test would be:

```
if ($node->type == 'insert_pub') {
  // ...
}
```

But it seems from your question you want to test the URL alias of the node, not the type. To do that you need to use [`drupal_get_path_alias()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7) to get the node's alias, and see if it matches:

```
$current_node_alias = drupal_get_path_alias("node/$node->nid");
if ($current_node_alias == 'insert-pub') {
  drupal_add_js('...
}
```

Make sure you've cleared Drupal's caches so the new preprocess hook can be picked up by the system. That's the only reason I can think of to explain the calls to `debug()` not working, as they should.