# Need clarification on adding JS to content item with JS injector and drupal_add_js

Tags: javascript

I want to put some js on my article. Original code form http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_p

is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

My article is at:   http://xuzo.com/testing/node/44

**Here is what I have done**

1. put this code in content item source code:

   ```
   <h2>This is a heading</h2>
   <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
   <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
   <p>Click me</p>
   ```
2. Put this in [JS Injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/js_injector) box:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
   $("p").hide();
   });
   });
   ```

and this for URL:

```
node/44
```

3. put this in my /public_html/testing/sites/all/themes/xuzo/template.php file:

   ```
   drupal_add_js('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js', 'external');
   ```
4. Flushed all cache
5. Not working!!! ;)

***Additionally...for this line of code to load JS files locally:***

```
drupal_add_js('misc/collapse.js');
```

Where to put the JS file? I take it misc can be any folder name? But where to put the files in relation to root? Sites/all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Create a **scripts** named folder **sites/all/themes/script**

2)Create a file in script folder **your-theme-name.js**

3)Paste this  **scripts[] = scripts/your-theme-name.js** in **.info** file of your theme

4)Put this code in content item source code:

```
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>Click me</p>
```

4)In **your-theme-name.js** put this code

Try to give some unique classes to paragraph elements like:

```
If (jQuery("body").hasClass("some-unique-class-in-bodytag-of-your-page"))
{
jQuery("body").find("p").addClass("abc");
}
```

5)Again In **your-theme-name.js** put this code

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("button").click(function() {
   jQuery("p").hasClass("abc").hide();
   });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Like Shrish mention your code needs to be like this

```
(function($) {
    // your code here
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            $("p").hide();
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

#### 2. your code says `$("button").click(function() {` but in your html there is no button:

```
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>Click me</p>
```

So change this to:

```
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<button>Click me</button>
```

#### 3. Checkmark inline js in JS Injector

[image]

Comment: This is working now, CKEDITOR was stripping <button> changing it to <P> tag...another issue. However, it works without drupal_add_js, why is that? If you use JS injector you don't need to use drupal_add_js ?

Comment: JS Injector is an alternative to drupal_add_js. JS Injector is more for programming noobs. If I had the choice, I rather use drupal_add_js as you can add it as a .js file and not as `<script>....</script>` which JS Injector does. The `<script>....</script>` is not SEO friendly.

Comment: Thank you No Ssssweat, I have a lot to learn....if I put all that code in a file,  and link to it using add_js, how can I control it to go only on page node/44 ?

Comment: @BrunoVincent see **[Add javascript to a specific node](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33221/add-javascript-to-a-specific-node)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your jquery code:

This is the error on your site: (Check browser console for this)

> TypeError: $(...).once is not a function

This is how you should be adding jquery code

```
(function($) {
    // your code here
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            $("p").hide();
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

OR, change your code to,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("button").click(function() {
        jQuery("p").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: I pasted the code you gave me  (second option) still not working, I don't know how to do option 1...;)

Comment: I have made the changes check now.

Comment: Thank you, I have pasted the edited code from 1st option,but  still not working...what should i put into "// your code here" ?

Comment: I see that you have added jquery library twice on your site, remove one you have hardcoded using `drupal_add_js` function. the other is coming from jquery_update module. check it's configuration here `http://xuzo.com/testing/admin/config/development/jquery_update`

Comment: I have removed the drupal_add_js form template.php  , checked the configuration of jquery, looks ok, not working...jQuery compression level
 Production (minified), Default jQuery Version 1.10, jQuery and jQuery UI CDN, jquery

Comment: clear cache ? I still see jquery in two places. check your source here: `view-source:http://xuzo.com/testing/node/44`

Comment: Cleared the cache

Comment: browser errors are now gone, but I don't see your script loaded on that page. :D something wrong with your configurations. It's always best way to include jquery and css on your code so that you can version control it. check this documentation `https://www.drupal.org/documentation/theme`